# Is it possible to add two phone numbers as links in a certain place on a JPGEG image via javascript/html/css

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I want to add two phone numbers on a picture, so that the user can click on the phone number (mobile view) and call it.

I use Wordpress Theme Accesspress Parallax and have add the image via theme options in a blank section.

To the Picture : I have photoshop two telephone numbers to a transporter like these [image: Picture with a car, which has a telephone number on]

Is it even possible to do something like this ?

Comment: Maybe this works for you, https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp

Comment: thanks thats one way ! i will try it thank you :), now i must find out how i can change the html code from the theme, because php create the html code with the settings of my theme options

Comment: thats it, it works fine :), how i can mark my question to answered ?

Comment: I can move it to a coment and mark it as response, wait a sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML area tag, used for mapping specific areas of a image to clickable elements.

Doc and examples here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
    .image { 
     position: relative; 
     width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
           }
    .phonenumber{ 
     position: absolute; 
     top: 100px; 
     left: 0; 
     width: 100%; 
     display: block;
     text-shadow: 2px 2px #ff0000;
     font-size: 2rem;
     font-weight: bold;
     color:blanchedalmond;
                 }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="image">
   <img src="http://www.imecar.com/wp-content/uploads/thumb-cache/CAG_8668-61f4fc962c673b1bc874ede912ae7086-500x400-100-crop.jpg"
        alt="" />
   <div class="phonenumber">
     <h2> here is your first phone number</h2>
     <h2>here is your second phone number</h2>
   </div>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```